# Excel formula not working in a table but works in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I have a very basic excel formula which works in a range but when I bring the data into a table the formula does not provide the correct results.

[image]

the formula is

```
=MAX([@[sub_date]]:[@[sup_date]])
```

when this data is in a range the formula is `Max(c2:d2)`

[image]

Why is this working in the range but not the table.

Comment: Try: `=MAX([@[sub_date]:[sup_date]])`

Comment: That gave me the same result

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, Your dates in the table are text that look like dates and not true dates.  They need to be converted to true dates.